# Using Moq to mock a repository that returns IQueryable<MyObject>

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq

How to I setup my Moq to return some values and having the tested service select the right one?

IRepository:

```
public interface IGeographicRepository
{
    IQueryable<Country> GetCountries();
}
```

Service:

```
public Country GetCountry(int countryId)
{
    return geographicsRepository.GetCountries()
             .Where(c => c.CountryId == countryId).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Can_Get_Correct_Country()
    {
        //Setup
        geographicsRepository.Setup(x => x.GetCountries()).Returns()
        //No idea what to do here.

        //Call
        var country = geoService.GetCountry(1); 
        //Should return object Country with property CountryName="Jamaica"

        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<Country>(country);
        Assert.AreEqual("Jamaica", country.CountryName);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, country.CountryId);
        geographicsRepository.VerifyAll();
    }
```

I'm basically stuck at the setup.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Couldn't you use [AsQueryable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx)?

```cs
List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
// Add Countries...
IQueryable<Country> queryableCountries = countries.AsQueryable();

geographicsRepository.Setup(x => x.GetCountries()).Returns(queryableCountries);
```

Comment: explain? I'm new to all this.

Comment: This is how I mock my IQueryable<T> repositories also.

Comment: This does make it unable to respon to  ToArrayAsync

Answer (score 2):

I suggest do not use AsQueryable(). it works only with some simple scenarios before you meet some specific methods on your ORM query language (Fetch, FetchMany, ThenFetchMany, Include, ToFuture and so on).

Better to use in memory database. Link below describes NHibernate Unit Testing.

> We can either use a standard RDBMS or use an in memory database such as SQLite in order to get very speedy tests.

http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write a private helper method that will generate an `IQueryable` of Country objects and have your mock return that.

```
[Test]
public void Can_Get_Correct_Country()
{
    // some private method
    IQueryable<Country> countries = GetCountries(); 

    //Setup
    geographicsRepository.Setup(x => x.GetCountries()).Returns(countries);

    //Should return object Country with property CountryName="Jamaica"
    //Call
    var country = geoService.GetCountry(1); 

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Country>(country);
    Assert.AreEqual("Jamaica", country.CountryName);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, country.CountryId);
    geographicsRepository.VerifyAll();
}
```

Comment: This is what they call writing a `stub`? So I have to rewrite stubs for all repository functions that return an IQuerable? Should I move all these stubs to a separate file inside the test project for each repository?

Comment: @Shawn: you would most likely be able to reuse the same stub for most of your unit tests, no? I would keep it in your test class.

Comment: How do I use Assert on an IQueryable?

Comment: @Shawn: What are you trying to Assert?